# How to get distinct values from an element within list of tuples in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, tuples, scala-collections

Hello I have this exercise where I am trying to find all numbers that do not exist in the second element of a tuple, and print them out in a list. I have a working version but it returns duplicate values, and it is not being returned in a list. I cant seem to use distinct here.  Can any one explain to me why distinct cannot be used here and what i would need to do instead.  Also if there is a better way to get the answer to the exercise, that would be appreciated.

```
 object Example{

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       val tupleExercise: List[(Int,Int)] = List(
         (1, 3),
         (2, 3),
         (3, 6),
         (5, 6),
         (5, 7),
         (4, 5),
         (4, 8),
         (4, 9),
         (9, 11)
       )

     def notExistsInSecond(n: List[(Int, Int)]): Unit = {
       var potential =
         for (a <- n) {
           for (c <- n) 
             if(c._1 == a._2) println(a._1)
         }
     }
     println(notExistsInSecond(tupleExercise))
   }
 }
```

```
//expected ouput
// [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Could you please add expected output? Do you want to return tuples, or just values of first tuple value, that are not present in second tuple value?

Comment: You can't use `.distinct` because there's nothing to use it on. You're printing the results instead of saving them. The last line, `println(notExists...` doesn't print anything but an empty `\n` because `notExistsInSecond()` returns `Unit`. If you save the results in a `List` then you could apply `.distinct`.

Comment: @RayanRal I've updated the expected output

Comment: @jwvh can i'm not sure how to save the results into a list, can you show the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a (performant) way to write it in one line, but you could write it like this:

```
def notExistsInSecond(n: List[(Int, Int)]): List[Int] = {
  val second = n.map(_._2).distinct
  n.map(_._1).distinct.filterNot(second.contains)
}
```

It gets probabely more performant if you use a `HashSet` instead of a `List` for the lookup:

```
def notExistsInSecond(n: List[(Int, Int)]): List[Int] = {
  val valuesSet = n.map(_._2).toSet
  n.map(_._1).distinct.filterNot(valuesSet.contains)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with a single pass through the input list and using `Set` to insure distinct results.

```
def notExistsInSecond(n: List[(Int, Int)]): List[Int] = {
  val (s1,s2) = n.foldLeft((Set.empty[Int],Set.empty[Int])){
    case ((sa,sb),(a,b)) => (sa+a, sb+b)
  }
  (s1 diff s2).toList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same logic as Raphael but more performant.

```
def notExistsInSecond[A](n: List[(A, A)]): List[A] = {
  val seconds = n.iterator.map(_._2).toSet

  val (result, _) = n.foldLeft(List.empty[Int] -> Set.empty[Int]) {
    case ((result, added), (e, _)) =>
      if (!seconds(e) && !added(e))
        (e :: result) -> (added + e)
      else
        result -> added
  }

  result.reverse // If you do not care about the order you can remove this reverse
}
```

Or if you do not care about the result being a list, this would be even faster:

```
def notExistsInSecond[A](n: List[(A, A)]): Set[A] = {
  val seconds = n.iterator.map(_._2).toSet

  n.iterator.collect {
    case (e, _) if (!seconds(e)) => e
  }.toSet
}
```

Comment: is there any benefit to call `iterator` on `n` if you convert it to a `Set` anyways?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth the iterator makes all subsequent transformations lazy. Thus the `map`, and the transformation to a set is done together in one iteration instead of in two.